# On Load jquery, divs bounce ui

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Hope someone can help i cant seem to get my head around this, i would like to load the jquery animation onload and let it to bounce unlmited number of times instead of having to click it.

Also it seems to bounce all my divs?

Any ideas here is what i have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  .bulb {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(img/bulb.png);
}

  </style>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("bounce", { times:500 }, 500);
});

  });
  </script>
</head>
<div class='bulb'></div>
<div>Dont Bounce</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bounce the element unlimited times, you have to create a function which calls itselved after the function is finished.

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zscGP/2/)

Give the element you want to bounce a certain class, in my case 'bounce' to only bounce this element.
So your html:

```
<div class='bounce'>bouncethis</div>
<div>Dont Bounce</div>
```

And your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    bounceDiv()
});

function bounceDiv() {
    $('.bounce').effect("bounce", { times: 1 }, 300,function() {
    bounceDiv()
    });
}
```

---

PS. I don't advice to do this, it's distracting, could be possible dangerous because it loops endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div")
```

Will choose ALL divs on the page, you might want to add a selector for the bouncing divs like:

```
<div class="bulb">bounce this</div>
<div>don't bounce</div>
```

the select it with:

```
$("div.bulb")
```

Also, if you want it to happen on mouseover, replace `.click` with `.mouseover`

Now to put it all together, you can do this:

```
$("div.bulb").effect(Bounce($(this))).mouseover(Bounce($(this)));
```

and outside the `$(document).ready`:

```
function Bounce(element) {
    element.effect("bounce", { times:500 }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript you've shown selects all divs, not just the one you want, to select just that one and to get it to bounce when the page loads replace this:

```
$("div").click(function () {
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times:500 }, 500);
});
```

with this:

```
$("div.bulb").effect("bounce", { times:500 }, 500);
```

Comment: @naspinski I ammended my answer as you typed your comment - I re read the question and it was asked that it should run on load, not click, so the above should do that now.

Answer (score 1):

To bounce only the one div, you should do this:

```
$("div.bulb").click(function () {
  $(this).effect("bounce", { times:500 }, 500);
});
```

If you want it to bounce right away you could do this after you bind the click behaviour:

```
$('div.bulb').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

To bounce on load:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.bulb").effect("bounce", { times:1 }, 500);
});
```

And to continue to bounce

```
$(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $("div.bulb").effect("bounce", {times:1}, 300);
    },300);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To bounce on load **and unlimited times:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gmtSS/

```
$(function(){
    bounce();
});
function bounce(){
    $('.bulb').effect("bounce", {times:1}, 500, function(){bounce();});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way imo is Matthews suggestion by binding the effect to the click event of the bulb and then call it directly by trigger(), like this you can call it on any event without the necessity of clicking the bulb.

What no one said until now is that your "times" parameter is quite an "overload", or do you really want to bounce it 500 times? Because of the effect itself (reducing the bounce distance after each bounce) you can't see any change after a few bounces anyway... 3 bounces every 200ms seems to get the most realistic effect.

My [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftSgS/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bulb').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 200);
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

If your goal was to repeatedly bounce the bulb the same way over a long period you should probably use animate() or something like that.

edit: slightly shortened code